# If $A \in C^{nxn}$ , $A \ge 0 $ and A is sing., there exists a sequence of matrices $C_k$, that $C_k \ge 0$,$|C_k| = 1$ and trace $AC_k \le 1/k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, trace, singular-values

**Question:** Show that if $A \in C^{n \times n}$ , $ A \ge 0 $ and A is singular, then there exists a sequence of matrices $C_k$, $k = 1,2,...$ such that $C_k \ge 0$, det $C_k = 1$ and trace $AC_k \le 1/k$

**My approach:** I have no idea how to even approach this exercise, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

*Hint.* If $A=B\oplus0_{(n-r)\times(n-r)}$ where $B>0$ and $r=\operatorname{rank}(A)$, consider $C=\left(\varepsilon I_r\right)\oplus\left(\varepsilon^{-r/(n-r)}I_{n-r}\right)$ for some positive scalar $\varepsilon$. What are $\det(C)$ and $\operatorname{trace}(AC)$ in this case?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. I'm still not sure how to find det($C$) and trace($AC$).

Comment: I do. But I don't understand how $C$ is constructed. Same about $A$.

Comment: @user1551 nice hint, $det(C)$ is indeed 1, but how do you calculate trace of $AC$  ,you dont know what is trace of $B$ after all... also how do you construct a sequence from that $C$?

Comment: @user2323232 The trace of $B$ is precisely the trace of $A$.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Do you know what is the direct sum of two matrices?

Comment: @user2323232 Huh? No. You have calculated the trace wrongly.

Comment: @user2323232 Sorry, I'll pass.